# Replace the html tags

Tags: sed, awk

My HTML code has the following line.

```
<TH>column1</TH><TH>column2</TH><TH>column3</TH>
```

Can I use sed tool to replace the column1 with "Name", column2 with "Surname" ...

```
<TH>Name</TH><TH>Surname</TH><TH>City</TH>
```

I have the list of the columns in a echo statement of my shell script.

```
echo 'Name, Surname, City'
```

These 3 values needs to be replaced in the respective columns in the HTML code. The number of columns might change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you change the input format of the new column names, or are you stuck with the `echo`. And does the table header line appear once per html file, or multiple times?

For your current situation, this would work:

```
echo 'Name, Surname, City' |
awk -F'<TH>|</TH><TH>|</TH>' 'NR==1{n=split($0,a,", *");OFS="";next}/<TH>/{for(i=1; i<=n;i++)$(i+1)="<TH>"a[i]"</TH>"}1' - file.html
```

Output:

```
<TH>Name</TH><TH>Surname</TH><TH>City</TH>
```

Note that things will go horribly wrong when your input html has a different form (additional or missing newlines). If you want to do anything more advanced you should use a proper SGML parser instead of `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I replace the file with the new contents? sed has -i swith. awk?

Comment: @shantanuo Awk has no `-i` switch. The standard way to do this (as in most UNIX programs) is something like `awk '[...]' old.html > new.html && mv new.html old.html`.

Answer (score 0):

put your replacements into variables instead of doing echo, then simply

```
sed 's|<TH>column1<\/TH>|<TH>Name</TH>|;s|<TH>column2</TH>|<TH>Surname</TH>|;s|<TH>column3</TH>|<TH>City</TH>|' file
```

Note, this is not fool proof if your pattern span multiple lines. But if all the things you need replaced is on one line, then it should be all right.